# Memory used by arrays

Tags: c, arrays, memory

I would like to know why this occurs. I am creating a 5-element array of integers - meaning each element takes 4 Bytes in the memory. Why when I print the address of myArray[-1] I also get a valid address?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int myArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

   printf("0x%p\n0x%p\n0x%p\n", &myArray[-1], &myArray[0], &myArray[1]);

   return 0;
}
```

Output:
0x0028FEF8
0x0028FEFC
0x0028FF00

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 'explain UB'

Answer (score 2):

Because undefined behavior is undefined: it may work or not, you are not guaranteed to get a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

The address isn't *valid*; it doesn't correspond to an object in your program.  Attempting to access that memory location results in *undefined behavior* - it *may* cause a runtime error.  Or not.

On almost any implementation, your array will be materialized in a larger region of storage, so naturally there will be memory cells on either side of that array (unless it starts at address 0, which it won't on almost any implementation you'll actually work on).  Since C doesn't enforce any kinds of bounds checking on array accesses, it doesn't immediately throw an exception when you use the -1 subscript.  Yes, you get what looks like a reasonable address value, but attempting to *use* that memory location may or may not result in some kind of mayhem depending on what's stored there (like a frame pointer, for example).  The language definition leaves the behavior *undefined*; it places no requirement on the compiler to do handle the situation in any particular way.  The compiler *may* issue a diagnostic that you're doing something stupid and halt translation.  It *may* compile the code without complaint, and you won't know anything's wrong until you get a runtime error.  It may do anything in between.